# В чем разница между salt и initialization vector (iv) при шифровании данных?

Tags: php, шифрование

На русском информации практически нет, а с английским у меня не очень хорошо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница между этими двумя понятиями. Особенно меня интересует шифрование данных.

Я раньше никогда ничего не шифровал, только хешировал. Я знаю, что соль - это случайная строка, которая хранится в файле конфига. Соль нужно добавлять перед / после строки, которая будет хешироваться - чтобы сложнее было разгадать хеш. Соль неизвестна и исходный текст (по которому получился хеш) подобрать, хешируя разные строки, нельзя.
Я написал про хеширование. Но ведь у соли будет тот же смысл и с шифрованием?

Я хочу научиться пользоваться функцией openssl_encrypt (это функция PHP). Там нет соли, там есть initialization vector. Я хочу понять, что это такое. И чем это отличается от соли.

Comment: Соль - для хеширования (и это не шифрование), IV для симметричного шифрования. У вас слишком общий вопрос, на той же википедии расписано, что такое IV и зачем он нужен.

Answer (score 1):

"Salt" и "Init vector" - вещи разные и вообще несвязанные. Соль используется при подготовке ключа, тогда как инициализационный вектор нужен для связывания блоков. Будем разбираться с ними отдельно и по порядку.

**Соль (salt)**

Для того, чтобы из текстового пароля произвольной длины сделать двоичный ключ фиксированной длины, который нужен для шифрующего алгоритма, используется хеш-функция.

```
key = hash("password")
```

В принципе этого достаточно, но что произойдет, если оппонент каким-то образом получит ключ? Хотя пароль он не узнает (хеш-функция по определению является односторонней), ему этого и не нужно - все файлы, зашифрованные данным паролем, окажутся доступны. Они ведь зашифрованы тем же самым ключом, и неважно из какого пароля этот ключ получен.

Для того, чтобы избежать такой ситуации, используется чуть более сложная система генерации ключа:

```
key = hash("password" + случайное_число)
```

Вот это самое "случайное число" и называется солью. Это число не является секретом, и обычно передается открыто в заголовке зашифрованного файла. Как это работает? Допустим, мы зашифровали два файла одним паролем. Ключи для них будут сгенерированы следующим образом:

```
key1 = hash("password" + salt1)
key2 = hash("password" + salt2)
```

Если оппонент получил `key1`, он не может получить из него пароль (как и в простой схеме). Он также не может получить `key2`, поскольку общего между этими ключами только пароль, который получить из первого ключа невозможно. Таким образом, даже при компрометации одного ключа, сам пароль, и другие зашифрованные файлы никак не пострадают.

Соль даже может не быть большой. Для небольших объемов шифрования вполне может хватить даже обычного целого числа (которое даст 4 миллиарда вариаций). 64-битовое число будет достаточным в любом случае.

В принципе можно придумать и более сложные схемы, например, соль можно шифровать простым хешем пароля. Сложно сказать, добавит ли это прочности шифру с математической точки зрения, но мороки оппоненту будет точно больше.

**Инициализационный вектор (initialization vector, IV)**

Симметричные шифры бывают блочными и потоковыми, при этом потоковые практически не используются. Блочный же шифр шифрует строго один блок, обычно 8, 16, или 32 байта. Исходный поток дополняется (padded) до размера, кратного размеру блока, или даже полностью декорируется ([пример](https://www.kryptel.com/articles/developers/stream.php)). Затем декорированный поток шифруется, блок за блоком.

Эта самая древняя и простая схема называется ECB (Electronic Code Book). Проблема с ней в том, что одинаковые входные данные дают одинаковые зашифрованные блоки. Вопрос тут не столько в надежности шифра (ECB достаточно надежен), сколько в том, что из анализа одинаковых блоков можно делать какие-то выводы о содержании файла. Особенно эта проблема актуальна для шифров с небольшим размером блока - DES, Triple-DES, Blowfish, и т.д.

Для борьбы с этим используется метод связывания блоков (block chaining). В простейшем случае это просто XOR с предыдущим блоком. Методов связывания придумали целую пачку - CBC, CFB, OFB, CTR - если интересно, можете почитать [здесь](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/81/archive/1980-12-02/documents/fips81.pdf).

Так вот, к чему все это - все методы связывания основаны на том, что текущий блок как-то замешивается с предыдущим. Есть вариации, но для простоты можно сказать так. Поэтому естественным образом возникает вопрос - с чем замешивать самый первый блок? Ответ: с неким искусственно сгенерированным "нулевым" блоком, который называется "инициализационным вектором". Вот, собственно, и все, что он из себя представляет - просто случайный стартовый блок для связывания.

Как и соль, IV не является секретом и передается в заголовке файла. Причем даже необязательно, чтобы он был случайным - нулевой IV точно так же закроет идентичные блоки. Но конечно, правильный IV должен генерироваться случайно. Его можно шифровать как и соль, от этого будет только лучше.

Comment: Нулевой IV закроет все блоки, кроме самого первого. Потом вы передадите еще одно сообщение с таким же префиксом в 16 байт, и злоумышленник увидит это. Асли вы шифруете одно и тоже сообщение с одинаковым IV, то злоумышленник всегда видит, что вы передаете одно и тоже сообщение.

Comment: "потоковые практически не используются" ну здесь как посмотреть. Сейчас почти на всех сайтах используется AES_GCM режим в TLS, а это фактически потоковый шифр, просто построенный на основе блочного. Паддингов там нет.

Comment: @Zergatul, я не предлагал использовать нулевой IV, это было просто примечание. Хотя страшного бы ничего не произошло, потому что есть и соль, и декорирование потока, и прочее, и прочее. 2) Давайте все же не путать - из блочного шифра можно сделать псевдо-потоковый, но потоковым он от этого не станет. Собственно, некоторые режимы связывания блоков это не что иное как блочный шифр в потоковом режиме. Тем не менее шифр остается блочным, потому что в основе своей он именно блочный, как бы с ним потом не извращались.

Comment: Что значит страшного ничего не произошло? Вы пишите про проблемы ECB, но CBC с нулевым IV в случае когда вы кодируете 1 блок превращается в ECB со всеми его проблемами.

Comment: @Zergatul, 1) Проблемы ECB с одинаковыми блоками, у CBC даже с нулевым вектором одинаковых блоков не будет. 2) Цитата: "_страшного бы ничего не произошло, потому что есть и соль, и декорирование потока, и прочее_". Имелось в виду, что даже с одинаковым паролем и одинаковыми данными потоки будут разными. 3) И наконец еще раз: я НЕ ПРЕДЛАГАЛ использовать нулевой IV. Я всего лишь заметил, что даже с нулевым IV связывание будет выполнять свою функцию.